# Why use template<> without specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I was reading the STL source code (which turned out to be both fun and very useful), and I came across this kind of thing

```
//file backwards/auto_ptr.h, but also found on many others.

template<typename _Tp>                                                                                                 
      class auto_ptr

//Question is about this:
template<>
    class auto_ptr<void>
```

Is the `template<>` part added to avoid class duplication?

Comment: Your title is confusing, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking what does the template<> is there for.

Comment: It's just the syntax used to say "This is a template class but I don't need any templates", because you'll be filling it in yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's specialization. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_void
{
    static const bool value = false;
};
```

This template would have `is_void<T>::value` as `false` for *any* type, which is obviously incorrect. What you can do is use this syntax to say "I'm filling in T myself, and specializing":

```
template <> // I'm gonna make a type specifically
struct is_void<void> // and that type is void
{
    static const bool value = true; // and now I can change it however I want
};
```

Now `is_void<T>::value` is `false` except when `T` is `void`. Then the compiler chooses the more specialized version, and we get `true`.

So, in your case, it has a generic implementation of `auto_ptr`. But that implementation has a problem with `void`. Specifically, it cannot be dereferenced, since it has no type associated with it.

So what we can do is specialize the `void` variant of `auto_ptr` to remove those functions.

Comment: Thank you, very well explained.